# c# asp.net redirect at end of code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to get it to redirect to a view after the database remove happens?
Got it to work once but couldnt figure out how.

```
        if (response.IsError == false && response.Paid)
        {
            // success
            offender offender = db.offenders.Find(id);
            db.offenders.Remove(offender);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return View("ThankYou");
```

Comment: Have you found any error ?

Comment: no it dont redirect.

Comment: Im not sure if im doing it the right way?

Comment: You can write `return RedirectToAction("ThankYou")`

Answer (score 0):

If you have Action method for `ThankYou` view then you can also write...

`return RedirectToAction("ThankYou")`

Comment: here is the action..

  public ActionResult Thankyou()
        {
            return View("ThankYou");

        }

Comment: You can try `return RedirectToAction("ThankYou")` insted of  `return View("ThankYou");`

Comment: System.Web.HttpException was unhandled by user code
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=Error executing child request for Thankyou.cshtml.
  Source=System.Web
  WebEventCode=0
  StackTrace:
       at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)